# Assigning a 16 bit number to two bytes of a buffer

Tags: c, variable

Currently I have this out buffer that I am assigning values to like this:

```
char out_buffer[OUT_DATA_SIZE];
…
out_buffer[7] = 0xD0;
out_buffer[6] = imu_union_ACC_Y.byte_data[1]
out_buffer[5] = imu_union_ACC_Y.byte_data[0];
out_buffer[4] = imu_union_ACC_X.byte_data[1];
out_buffer[3] = imu_union_ACC_X.byte_data[0];
out_buffer[2] = imu_union_ACC_Z.byte_data[1];
out_buffer[1] = imu_union_ACC_Z.byte_data[0];
out_buffer[0] = 0xC0;
```

I would like to assign a `int16_t` value to two of the bytes. The variable name is `a_y_filtered`. So essentially instead of sending out x,y  and z. I'd like to send x, y, and y filtered.

Comment: You should show the declaration of out_buffer, shift and or operations can do what you want.

Comment: Alrighty, I added it

Comment: This isn't a well defined problem, as you have to consider both endianess and support (vs non-support) for *unaligned access* on a particular processor.  Things like aliasing memory with unions or pointers can work, but require a detailed understanding of what you are doing.  Mathematical decomposition and recomposition can be more clearly explicit, but you have to be very careful of sign extension...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a union was sufficient for my purposes.

```
  out_buffer[7] = 0xD0;
  out_buffer[6] = a_x_filtered.byte_data[1];
  out_buffer[5] = a_x_filtered.byte_data[0];
  out_buffer[4] = imu_union_ACC_X.byte_data[1];
  out_buffer[3] = imu_union_ACC_X.byte_data[0];
  out_buffer[2] = imu_union_ACC_Z.byte_data[1];
  out_buffer[1] = imu_union_ACC_Z.byte_data[0];
  out_buffer[0] = 0xC0;
```

Here's the union structure:

```
typedef union
{
  uint8_t byte_data[2];
  int16_t g_x;
}imu_union_t;
```

And this is how i declared it:

```
imu_union_t a_x_filtered;
imu_union_t a_y_filtered;
imu_union_t a_z_filtered;
```

Comment: Or if you meant this to be an answer, then you need to realize that this depends on information that isn't given in the question. The question doesn't say architecture is used, so we don't know whether `byte_data[0]` is the MSB or LSB of `g_x`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to split an unsigned 16-bit int into two 8-bit numbers is to:

1. Store the 16-bit int in a new 8-bit int to capture the LSB.
2. Shift the 16-bit int 8 bits to the right and store the result in the 8-bit MSB int.

Given 16-bit unsigned int combined_int:

```
uint8_t lsb_int = combined_int;

uint8_t msb_int = combined_int >> 8;
```